# Making a function generic where the Generic type must support a add or + function

Tags: scala

I have two case classes in Scala that look like this:

```
case class User(name:String, countA:Int, countB:Int)

case class Store(l: User, a: Iterable[User], b: Iterable[User]) {

  def longFoldLeft(s: Long)(f: (Long, User) => Long): Long = {
    val foldLeftB = b.foldLeft(s)(f)
    val foldLeftA = a.foldLeft(foldLeftB)(f)
    val result = f(foldLeftA, l) 
    result
  }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to create a function in *Store* class that performs a foldLeft on a and b and finally appends the results on *l*.

Now I want to make sure the resultant type supports a *+* method. Is that possible in scala? If yes, then how?

Comment: the function you have written is working you  just want to make it generic?

Comment: you can make your typeA and typeB as a subType of anyVal as in scala all the values are the subtype of anyVal. Like Int, Double etc.

Comment: Yes your right. The function is working fine and I want to make it generic. However, the result type must support a add or + function.

Comment: what is typeA and typeB?

Comment: typeA is a variable of type Iterable[User]

Comment: How typeA and type B are avalible in your function longFoldLeft?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin An incorrect version of the code contained the + or add, however now it doesn't. I recently edited the question to fix that.

Comment: But now you can simply replace `Long` by an arbitrary type parameter `[T]`, and it would still work. Why do you want to ask for more constraints than necessary?

Comment: You are right, I will delete the question!

Comment: Not sure whether it will work, because now there are answers with positive score...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't delete it now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use structual typing:

```
def longFoldLeft[T <: { def +(v: T): T}](s: T)(f: (T, User) => T): T = {
  f(lead)  + typeA.foldLeft(typeB.foldLeft(s)(f))(f)
}
```

See also: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types

Comment: Actually it throws the following error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement.

Comment: My IDE initially didn't show any error so I thought that the code worked. Additionally I found another error in my code. Function f expects two parameter so f(l) is invalid. Instead it should be f(foldLeftA, l). I have corrected it in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to just replace `Long` by an unconstrained type parameter `T`:

```
  def foldLeft[T](s: T)(f: (T, User) => T): T = {
    val foldLeftB = b.foldLeft(s)(f)
    val foldLeftA = a.foldLeft(foldLeftB)(f)
    f(foldLeftA, l) 
  }
```

If the user of this API later wants to use it with `Long`, `Int`, any subtype of [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html), or a type for which there is an instance of [`Monoid`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html), then it's still possible. No reason to impose unnecessary constraints on `T`.